# How to show merged data from two SharePoint lists with same columns using PowerApps gallery?

Tags: sharepoint, powerapps, power-automate, powerapps-canvas

I have two SharePoint lists A and B which have 3 same columns and a different column which have their respective lists name as its metadata e.g. "TaskId","TaskTitle" and "Department","List". I want to merge the data from both the lists and display it in PowerApps gallery which show current data every time it is opened. I assume that we will store the data from both the lists in two separate collections and then merge those collections into a third collection and display it in a gallery. The output should be as shown in the **picture**.

Comment: Have you looked into the COLLECT function?  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powerapps/maker/canvas-apps/functions/function-clear-collect-clearcollect

Comment: Yes, but how are we supposed to merge the two collections then in a vertical manner?